# Highcharts Column Chart Drilldown

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

Can anybody give an example of drill down functionality for column charts of Highcharts package? Here is the jsfiddle of the example from the Highcharts website but it is with static data. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/

How to make it dynamic? Even if I implement the click function, how to know which column was clicked? How to refresh the same chart with drilldown data? I have complex XML which I converted to an array of objects. So preparing drilldown data is not a problem. But I need guidance on passing this data to the chart. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what you have to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/yPVX9/2/

I used the same code that you gave on the link.

Hope this help you :)

Comment: Thanks :)...this is indeed what I was looking for. I have seen your comment on my other question regarding that point click problem. I think first I will have to sort that out before I can use this. I have added my comment there and I will provide my code tomorrow. :)